# Flutter ListView.Builder results in choppy scrolling. How do I make the scrolling smooth?

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-listview

I’m trying to build an app which has a list of bookings that loads. When the user scrolls through those bookings, the scrolling is very choppy. I’ve done the testing on all debug, profile and release modes but the issue with choppy scrolling still remains. This is true for both iOS and Android. Here’s what I have already tried -

1. I’ve already tried using const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
2. I’ve tried using without animation and with animation. The choppy scrolling is present in both the cases
3. I’ve tried the cached.network.image. Choppy scrolling present.

The ListView builder takes more than 16ms to build the ListTile even  in profile mode

[image: ListView Performance overlay]

```
return ListView.builder(
      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: widget.bookings.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        var count = 10;
        var animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animationController,
            curve: Interval((1 / count) * index, 1.0,
                curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn)));
        animationController.forward();

        return BookingListCard(
          booking: widget.bookings[index],
          bookings: widget.bookings,
          animation: animation,
          animationController: animationController,
        );
      },
    );
```

```
AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation,
          child: new Transform(
            transform: new Matrix4.translationValues(
                0.0, 50 * (1.0 - animation.value), 0.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0),
              child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                onTap: () {
                  callback();
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    color: AppTheme.halfWhite,
                    elevation: 0,
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context)
                            .push(_createRoute(booking, booking.id));
                      },
                      leading: Container(
                        width: _size,
                        height: _size,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(booking.guest.imageUrl),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                        child: Text(
                          booking.guest.firstName,
                          style: AppTheme.title,
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                '${(DateFormat("E, d MMM").format(DateTime.parse(booking.checkIn))).toUpperCase()}  ',
                                style: AppTheme.caption,
                              ),
                              Image.asset(
                                "assets/images/arrow.png",
                                width: 12,
                                height: 12,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '  ${(DateFormat("E, d MMM").format(DateTime.parse(booking.checkOut))).toUpperCase()}',
                                style: AppTheme.caption,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                            child: DashedDivider(
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                                dashWidth: 0.1),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '${(booking.status).toUpperCase()}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: statusColorFinder(booking.status),
                              fontFamily: AppTheme.fontName,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 12,
                              letterSpacing: 0.4,
                              height: 0.9,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      // trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                      trailing: booking.status == 'Pending' ? MyBullet() : null,
                      isThreeLine: false,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: tried the most simple `ListView.builder` example from the official documentation? does it go choppy too?

Comment: It is still choppy with the example from official documentation

Comment: so you have only one `ListView` and nothing more? no async tasks, no isolates etc?

Comment: Why you're again and again declaring animation? just declare it once in your state class and reuse the variable instead of defining again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Running  on profile mode able to trace out the issue it was  i generated dashe line 
using  list builder  rather  than using  contianer which was the cause for the lag
replaced the following code

```
 DashedDivider(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
dashWidth: 0.1)
```

with this one

```
Container(color: Colors.black45,
height: 1,
width: double.maxFinite,
)
```

Comment: so i was asking you about the most simple `ListView.builder` example from the official documentation, why did you say it is choppy too?

Comment: In official example also at some places it takes more than 50ms during scrolling which results in choppy

Comment: so If the simplest example is choppy then your much more complex code would be choppy too, don't you think? I mean there must be something wrong  in your development environment

Comment: Yes for the complex one I was able to get to below 20 ms which is fine but not the right fix. For the development environment I tried with  two different pc its still the same

Comment: It sounds like this was fixed in v1.12.13. Is it any better for you now?
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22314